# How can I get data from vuex store in vue2 app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, store

I'm vue newbie.

I created a vuex store, and I want to get state in App.vue

But in vuedevtools, I have an error like this.

How can I fix?

store codes:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);


const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    symbols: 'test',
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
});

export default store;
```

app.vue :

```
import { mapState,  } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      symbols: state => state.symbols
    }),
    // ...mapGetters(["getSymbols"]),
  },
```

main.js codes:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  render : h => h(App),
  store,
})
```

devtools error screenshot :

[devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLwmX.png)

Comment: You need to add a method in `getter` that will return the value.

Comment: adding a getter is unrelated to the problem, you _could_ use a getter but `mapState` should still work fine. I do see based on the syntax that it looks like Vuex 3.  Is there a reason?  The latest version is Vuex 4, however the current officially recommended state management tool for Vue is now [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html) (which is itself a continuation/rebranding of Vuex). Always best to use the latest recommended tools as support for older versions die off and number of incompatibility issues grows larger.

Comment: If you must use Vuex 3, try just adding `<div>{{ symbols }}</div>` somewhere in your template.  do you get any error messages in your console or is the data displayed ok?